# Botkit with mysql instead of mongodb

Tags: javascript, mysql, botkit

Does anyone know how to use mysql with botkit instead of mongodb?

I've tried installing Mysql for botkit as seen here https://www.npmjs.com/package/botkit-storage-mysql

and I added the code provided to my bot.js file.

How can I do a simple test to see if its working if this is working.

I can't enter mysql shell in the app folder via terminal, I'm guessing there's something wrong.

The app runs fine on **node .**

Answer (score 0):

botkit-storage-mysql is not a general purpose storage module, it is coded specifically to store details of Slack sessions and it isn't suitable for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have it running using MySQL just fine. You need to have the MySQL Middleware https://www.npmjs.com/package/botkit-storage-mysql.

Alternatively you can download the middleware from the github repo and modify it to suit your needs (if the license allows it). Put it in your middlewares directory and include it in your bot.js https://github.com/getforgex/botkit-storage-mysql/tree/master/src